# How to create a new user and add multiple user attributes into firestore as a transaction?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an new user using firebase.auth.onCreate();
I want to create a user with multiple extra attributes (ie gender, age). I don't know how this can be done as a transaction or how to pass extra attributes into this onCreate so the cloud function just add the extra attributes into firestore.

I am creating the new user with email, password, displayName and a default profileImage. I can add the displayName, email and profileImage into firestore using a onCreate cloud function. The problem arises where   if add the extra fields in a then from the promise returned from creating the user in auth is that if creating the user is successful but then adding the extra essential info about the user in the database fails then I have a half baked user. I don't want to delete the user completely if the firestore.firestore().collection()...set() call fails (its a hacky solution).

This way if creating the user is successful but adding user into firestore fails the entire user registration will fail if I use a transaction. If I can pass the extra attributes then at least the chance of the cloud function failing due to client side errors is basically nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An onCreate handler for Firebase Auth always happens **after** the new user is already created.  You can't "fail" the creation of the user with the function trigger.

If you're worried that the update to Firestore might fail, you should [enable retries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries) so that Cloud Functions can try again later.

But you shouldn't need a transaction to create a new user document in Firestore.  The user's UID will be unique, which means the document with the same ID shouldn't already exist.

Comment: So createUserWithEmailandPassword returns a promise. Do I then do a collection().doc().set the gender, age and other values in the then()

Comment: So if I create a user using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword but then the set call fails how do delete the user? I don't want to create the user if I can't set the extra essential information about them in firestore. Also thank you for your youtube videos on firebase!

Comment: Then delete the user with delete.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#delete

Comment: But what happens if the reason why set call fails is because internet connection is lost so that means you cannot delete either. So now there is a user that is created with no info on them. Sorry I am going down such a minute scenario. Maybe I can just remote the users to add the extra info in again to add it to the database. If there is a better approach to this very small usecase let me know and thank you in advance!

Comment: The document set will not fail due to lack of network. It will automatically retry until it synchronizes. You should instead be thinking about ways to correct bad situations at app launch rather than trying to undo every possible failure situation.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you